# Querying data in s3 using parquet or s3 select

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, apache-arrow

So i have a parquet format files in s3 and want to run queries on them. I have looked into using S3 select in Java. Someone mentioned Arraow as an alternative has anyone used parquet?

Im sending this data to FE.

Comment: S3 Select and AWS Athena are the two services you should be evaluating for querying parquet files. Perhaps Redshift external tables as well. I don't see any need to use Apache Arrow unless the files are really small and you don't mind downloading them from S3 whenever you read them.

Comment: This is a pretty abstract question and there are many libraries out there that can try and solve it.  For efficient querying you will want to download the files into a local cache, run them through some kind of query engine, and then forward the results where you want to go.  Apache Arrow can help with downloading to a local cache but it's not an end-to-end solution for this kind of problem in the way that Redshift would be.  There are regrettably too many factors at play to give any concrete best answer.